# Why do turbo props have their engine controls like condition levers next to each other when other planes have them mixed up?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-controls

Comparing cockpits of the CRJ and the ATR. I noticed that turbo props have the throttle and condition lever next to each other. When the crj has just a throttle. and then some switches for fuel control. Why is this?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My understanding is that it is mostly a historical convention to make the turboprop engine controls resemble the spark-ignition piston engine controls that had mixture.

Turboprop engines usually have power, prop speed, and condition levers. Power should be obvious. Prop speed sets the prop speed as turboprops always have constant-speed propellers. And condition usually servers two functions: a fuel cutoff (which is what mixture is used for in spark-ignition piston engines), and switch between low and high idle.

Low idle is the minimum speed at which the engine will continue to run, but from that speed it is rather slow to accelerate when more power is commanded. So the high idle is a higher minimum speed from which the control response is considered adequate, to be used in flight.

The low/high idle could be just detents on the power lever, and that's what they are on jet (turbojet and turbofan) engines, when they are used and not completely automated based on weight-on-wheels sensor. And of course jets don't have any variable pitch propellers to control speed of, so all they have left is power and simple master and ignition switches.

Some turboprops have reduced the condition to a small lever or switch it can be, or merged the condition functions to the other two controls: combined cut-off with feather, and made ground/flight idle just the power lever detents. And some reduced even the prop lever to three positions: max rpm for take-off and landing, some pre-set lower value for economic cruise, and feather for if the engine fails.

Note that I specifically say spark-ignition. Compression-ignition, that is Diesel, piston engines don't have mixture control either. I don't know how the controls of the historical ones looked, but Diamond aircraft with Diesel engines don't have anything like condition, just engine master.

Comment: @Bianfable, almost all turboprops have FADEC these days, but the controls vary a bit.